# How to disable the Missing "use strict" statement by jshint in Sublime 3?

Tags: javascript, ide, sublimetext3, jshint

I have added `"strict": false` to the default `.jshintrc`, yet Sublime 3 still shows the "Missing 'use strict'" In-Editor warning.

Any help how to disable this warning?

Here is my complete `.jshintrc`:

```
{
  // Details: https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint#using-your-own-jshintrc-options
  // Example: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc
  // Documentation: http://www.jshint.com/docs/
  "browser": true,
  "camelcase": true,
  "devel": true,  // to suppress 'console' and 'alert'
  "esnext": true,
  //"eqnull": true,
  "expr": true, // This option suppresses warnings about the use of expressions
  "globals": {
    "_": false,
    "angular": false
  },
  "globalstrict": false,
  "strict": false,
  "predef": ["angular"],
  "quotmark": true,
  "smarttabs": true,
  "trailing": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true
}
```

Comment: The above config should work, if you want to disable / enable strict mode on a single file you can write: `/* jshint strict: false */`

Comment: It seems [other people have had this issue](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2/issues/303). Are you using the latest version of Sublime Linter?

Answer (score 3):

You need go to sublime text3 > preferences > package settings > jshint gutter > set linting preferences and in this file .jshintrc change option "strict": "false". Then restart you sublimeText3

Answer (score 3):

As stated by andlrc, the simpliest solution would be to specify to jshint to skip strict restriction on this file by adding at the top of it :

`/* jshint strict: false */`